# Access to the leafs of Composite pattern Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite

I implement the Composite pattern for represent a tree of elements like in the picture:
[image]

But how I can access to the leafs of this tree, like a List of Leaf. Should I implement Visitor?

Comment: show your implementation

Answer (score 0):

Leaves are implemented like this:

```
public class Leaf{

  private List<Leaf> leaves;

  ......
}
```

*And for that you ideally won't need to have any other Design Pattern.*

You can think of this as a relationship between a **Manager** and **Employee**.

A Manager who is an Employee can have a list of Employees who work under that Manager.

```
public class Employee{

  private List<Employee> workingUnderHim;

  ......
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you; but if I would like to have a list of all the leafs, like in this case the list of all the Employee?

Comment: @MaVeRicK_91 Where do you want to keep it? If you need to get the lIst of Employees from the Employee class you can just have a getter for that field.

Comment: I don't agree with this. `Leaf` is just a leaf, it doesn't have any knowledge of the other leafs. The example you give is misleading because you only have one class Employee which is a leaf and a composite at the same time, but does not illustrate the general case.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have taken the class diagram from wikipedia, but sadly it is wrong. This one is accurate, regarding the GoF book:

[image: Composite Design Pattern]

As you can see, the association between `Component` and `Composite` isn't the same:

- A `Composite` aggregates `Component`s (for example you could store them in a List)
- A `Leaf`has no children

Also, `Composite` has a method `getChild(int n)` to get the nth child component (you could simply get the nth element of the previous list)

To get all the the leaves for a given root Component, I guess you could use one of these [Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) algorithms.

Comment: Ok, but the method getChild return the nth child of the object composite, that could not be the nth leaf element of a List of Component.

Comment: Sure, it was just to point the fact that the wikipedia was not as wrong as I said, but a bit imprecise...